# Maximum likelihood estimator for a mixture of 2 distributions

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, mixture-distribution

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid with one of two PDFs.

If $\theta = 0$, then

$f(x; \theta) = 1, \ 0 < x < 1$.

if $\theta = 1$, then

$f(x; \theta) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}, \ 0 < x < 1$.

What is the MLE of $\theta$?

I can define the likelihood function in terms of indicator functions for $\theta$, but then I don't know how to use differentiation to maximize it.  Please help.

Comment: Is $\theta$ a parameter? It looks like a latent variable.

Comment: "Maximize" doesn't automatically imply "differentiate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$ the logarithm of the sampling density is:

$$\ln f(x|\theta) = \begin{cases} 
0 & & \text{for } \theta=0, \\[6pt] 
-\ln 2 - \tfrac{1}{2} \ln x & & \text{for } \theta=1. \\[6pt] 
\end{cases}$$

So you have the log-likelihood function:

$$\ell_\mathbf{x}(\theta) = \begin{cases} 
0 & & \text{for } \theta=0, \\[6pt] 
-n \ln 2 - \tfrac{1}{2} \sum \ln x_i & & \text{for } \theta=1. \\[6pt] 
\end{cases}$$

This is a binary function (only two possible inputs) and so you maximise it by comparing the outputs for those two inputs.  (There is no differentiation involved.)  Define $T(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \tfrac{1}{n} \sum |\ln x_i|$, which is the average absolute logarithm of the data (this is a sufficient statistic).  Maximising this function yields the MLE:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\hat{\theta}(\mathbf{x}) 
&= \mathbb{I} \Big( \ell_\mathbf{x}(1) > \ell_\mathbf{x}(0) \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{I} \Big( -n \ln 2 - \tfrac{1}{2} \sum \ln x_i > 0 \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{I} \Big( - \tfrac{1}{2} \sum \ln x_i > n \ln 2 \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{I} \Big( \tfrac{1}{n} \sum |\ln x_i| > 2 \ln 2 \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{I} ( T(\mathbf{x}) > 2 \ln 2 ). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

(Note that the MLE is not uniquely determined for the case where $T(\mathbf{x}) = 2 \ln 2$.  In this case either parameter value gives the same log-likelihood value.  This means that you can use non-strict inequality in the above MLE formula and this still gives a valid MLE.)

Comment: How did you know to maximize $T(x)$??

Comment: How did you obtain the first line for $\hat{\theta}(x)$?

Comment: @MSE: I have added a new first line to this equation to show you - all I am doing is setting $\hat{\theta} = 1$ if $\ell_\mathbf{x}(1) > \ell_\mathbf{x}(0)$, and setting it to zero otherwise.  As to using $T(\mathbf{x})$, that is just a convenient way to express the final result in terms of a simple sufficient statistic.